# Clicking a button in included page has to trigger click event on main page

Tags: jquery

I have 3 sections on jsp page and second section is a separate included jsp. From the included jsp if i click the submit button then it has to trigger a button in the main jsp page. please let me know how to do this using jquery
Here is some way i am planning to do this. 'showdiv' is a button within included page and 'fileupload' is a button on main page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#showdiv").click(function(){
        window.$("#FileUpload").trigger("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: keep the jquery click even in main page.

Comment: can you give some example code to do this

Comment: Here is some way i am planning to do this.<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#showdiv").click(function(){
        window.$("#FileUpload").trigger("click");
    });
});
</script>